# She ran ....the path and .... the steps and .... her house

Tags: prepositions

> She ran ______ the path and ______ the steps and ______ her house.

options:

a) from/into/into

b) along/towards/into

c) along/up/into

d) by/on/into

e) in/next to/near

MyApproach:

I am confused between b) and c)

Reason: In the second fill up I think towards should be there because it indicates in the direction of which correlates with the sentence

I found the meaning of ***up*** also that correlates in the sentence is:

> "from a lower to a higher point on (something); upward along: ***she climbed up a flight of steps.***"

Can Anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: "c" is correct as up refers to the movement.

Comment: I personally prefer running **down** the path. Let's see what our native speakers have got to say.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with this question, and these kind of tests. Any of the five choices make grammatical sentences in English.

One can argue that C is the *best* answer, as it talks about one action of running:

"run along the path, up the steps and into one's house."

But B is not incorrect, as one can

"run along the path, towards the steps and into one's house."

Maybe the steps are a landmark that shows the direction of the house.

Likewise, A, D and E do not make ungrammatical sentences. But one assumes they are not examples of the kind of sentence and use of prepositions that the test is testing.

Answer (score -1):

you can split the sentence into few phrase:
1, she ran along the path; 2, she climbbed up the steps; 3, she got into her house;

Aparently, her house is built few steps above the pavement.

Answer (score -2):

c) is correct in this case. If she ran along the path towards the steps, it implies that she may have stopped when she reached the bottom of the steps.